# How to understand variables in python code

Tags: python, variables

I'm new to python. I have just started working on a python project that has been in development for some time. So, there's a substantial amount of code in existence, and I need to understand it and be able to add to it, change it.

I am having serious problems with pythons dynamic typing when trying to understand existing code.

Let's say variable `A` is created in function `fn1`, then passed down to `fn2`, which passes it down to `fn3`, which passes it down to `fn4`. If I am looking at `fn4`, I can see `A` on the input but I have no idea what type it is, what it does. I need to navigate through `fn4` to `fn3`, to `fn2`, all the way to `fn1` to just see how A was populated and therefore understand what the class of `A` is. This seems like a ridiculously laborious process to go through.

Do you have any hints how to more efficiently understand what is contained in python variables?

Comment: One way is to just run the code, but with a breakpoint just inside `fn4()`. When the program stops, you can inspect what `A` contains to see what types are passed in.

Comment: You can add [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and build / document your understanding of the code base this way. As a bonus, type checkers and IDEs can use that information as well.

Comment: Python does support typing *if* you use it. If not, yes, you do sort of have to speculate and follow the various paths that lead to that function.

Comment: But on a professional/interpersonal note: don't ask us. Ask the folks you work with. Mentoring, and being mentored, is a core part of being part of a team.

Comment: Welcome to the dynamic typing world (or hell) :)

Comment: If you find a function in a codebase unmeaningful or vague, then it's very likely that the codebase is unconventional (e.g. single letter variables), not very well-designed (e.g. single responsibility principle violation) or badly documented (e.g. no document at all or, even worse, an incorrect one).

Answer (score 0):

Of course type hints help a lot.

You could also look at unit tests, which can help.

But if you do not have any type hints, look at what fn4 does of A. Imagine fn4 calls len(A) and nothing else, that means that A could be for example a list, a tuple, a string... And when looking at fn4, it does not matter if it is a list or a tuple (this is duck typing : fn4 could work with anything that has a length)